# Some confusion about definition of univalent function

Tags: complex-analysis

I was studying about univalent function from this pdf .
But in this pdf, it is written that function is univalent if it is injective. But I have read many places that function is univalent if it is analytic and one one in given domain. So I am really confused whether I should read this pdf or not. Please guide.

Comment: http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/LectureNotes/univalent.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theory of "univalent functions" in complex analysis is all about univalent analytic functions.  This particular author seems to want to separate the "injective" and "analytic" parts.   I don't know why. So he might say that
a function is "analytic and univalent" where someone else, for whom "analytic"
is part of the definition of univalent, would just say "univalent".  I don't know if he ever says anything about non-analytic one-to-one functions, which he might call "univalent", while the other author would just call it "injective".

But a 
little bit of terminological eccentricity is not a reason to discard the pdf.